# Permission Feature activation/deactvation. How do I reset default permissions again?

Tags: permissions, feature-activation

Basically what I want to do is give admin the ability to lock an aspx for certain users through a read-only permission feature, so they can't upload/remove documents if the "case" is closed.

The first if-statement seems to work, I manage to set the permissions to read-only when the case is saved as closed.

The problem I have is trying to reset default permissions so everyone can contribute when the case is open again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    protected void SaveCaseInfoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //check if user Admin && dropdownvalue stängt
            if (Utilities.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(SPContext.Current.Web, "Admin") && this.CaseStatusDropDown.SelectedValue == "Closed")
            {
                // Check if {f1dc9cc0-3cec-433a-a1e6-4a13fb87c1d9 is activated on SPContext.Current.Web
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                if (web.Features[new Guid("f1dc9cc0-3cec-433a-a1e6-4a13fb87c1d9")] != null)
                {

                    // if avtiveated, remove
                    web.Features.Remove(new Guid("f1dc9cc0-3cec-433a-a1e6-4a13fb87c1d9"));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Activate feature
                    web.Features.Add(new Guid("f1dc9cc0-3cec-433a-a1e6-4a13fb87c1d9"));
                }                    
            }
            if (Utilities.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(SPContext.Current.Web, "Admin") && this.CaseStatusDropDown.SelectedValue == "Open")
            {
        // Try to reset the default permissions     
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                if (web.Features[new Guid("58143549-2823-4037-8238-a41af70dfad1")] != null)
                {

                    // Remove
                    web.Features.Remove(new Guid("58143549-2823-4037-8238-a41af70dfad1"));

                }
                else
                {
                    // Activate feature
                    web.Features.Add(new Guid("58143549-2823-4037-8238-a41af70dfad1"));

                }                    
            }
```

Comment: What features are you enabling / disabling above?

Comment: the first one is one I made stripping users of contribute rights, the one in the second if block are the default settings